# Retrieve data from an input form and make a get request spring mvc

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, javabeans

I want to take the data from an input form(log in data->password+username) and save it into a bean. Then, i want to take this bean and the data inside and make a get reuest.

I declare a class:

```
public class Login {



private String username;
private String password;




public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

}
```

The getrequest is the following:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/log",method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String addPersonLogin( Model model,HttpServletRequest request) {

       //take the bean here
    }
```

Can anyone tells me how can i create the jsp and how can i treat the bean into the addPersonLogin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it that way (using @ModelAttribute):

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    // You can register your validator for bean Login here
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/log",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addPersonLogin(@ModelAttribute Login login, HttpServletRequest request) {
    // To make it work your form fields should have names equals to bean fields names
    login.getUserName();
    login.getPassword();
}
```

Comment: When you say i can register my validator what exactly do you mean?how can i do this?

Comment: You can create validator to check input data from user. Validator should implements Validator interface. Than you register it caling binder.setValidator(yourValidator). And change method of  controller: public String addPersonLogin(@ ModelAttribute @ Valid Login login, HttpServletRequest request, BindingResult bindingResult). To use @ Valid you should import bean-validator.jar from J2EE from sun. Than in method bindingResult.hasError() you can check is there errors and get this error. @ Valid will force to call validation.